# How Do I Use Slick When I Don't Know the Returned Types at Compile Time?

Tags: scala, resultset, slick

I'm using Slick but I can't define a type at compile time to hold the query result. Instead, the application requirements specify the columns to retrieve at runtime.

I've tried an implicit like below, but when I run my test program (just a simple query for one row) the application hangs forever.

```
  implicit val getResultSet: GetResult[ResultSet] = GetResult(r => r.rs)
```

Just to rule out something else, I tried the code below and it works (as expected).

```
  case class TestResult(id: Int, site_id: Int, url: String, name: String)

  implicit val getTestResult = GetResult(r => TestResult(r.nextInt, r.nextInt, r.nextString, r.nextString))
```

I tried the following, but the application hangs forever using this approach, too.

```
implicit val getResultMap: GetResult[Map[String,Object]] = new GetResult[Map[String,Object]] {
def apply(pr: PositionedResult) = {
  val rs = pr.rs
  val md = rs.getMetaData()
  val res = for {
    i <- 1 to pr.numColumns
  } yield md.getColumnName(i) -> rs.getObject(i)
  pr.nextRow
  res.toMap
}   
}
```

I guess I'm missing something fundamental. There's gotta be a way to make this work.

Comment: OK. So I did some digging and found this:                                   `implicit val resultAsObjectMap = GetResult[Map[String,Object]] ( prs => 
      (1 to prs.numColumns).map(_ => 
         prs.rs.getMetaData.getColumnName(prs.currentPos+1) -> prs.nextString
      ).toMap
   )`                 My question is why does this work and the other attempts didn't?